# Code Analysis - CA1704: Correct the spelling of 'Ps'

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, suppress-warnings

I am getting the following warning from Code Analysis in VS2010

> CA1704 : Microsoft.Naming : Correct
>   the spelling of 'Ps' in member name
>   'MyClass.PsCalculatedAmount' or remove
>   it entirely if it represents any sort
>   of Hungarian notation.

Now in my codebase 'Ps' means 'Per Share' and is used heavily, so I would like to allow it as an acceptable word/acronym.

I tried adding it to my CustomDictionary.xml under

```
<Words>
    <Recognized>
        <Word>ps</Word>
...
    <Recognized>
<Words>
```

and also tried

```
<Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
        <Acronym>Ps</Acronym>
    ...
    <CasingExceptions>
<Acronyms>
```

but I still get the warning.

Is there something I should be doing differently?

I noticed that there had been a bug in FXCop regarding this which is now fixed;
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstscode/thread/54e8793c-e821-49b2-80db-ea1420acf1e6

Is there a chance that this bug still exists in the version of Visual Studio i am using: V10.0.30319?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's being rejected because it's flagged as an unrecognized word in the "root" custom dictionary in Code Analysis installation folder (usually %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop).  You'll need to remove it from the root dictionary unrecognized list before adding it as a recognized word in a project-specific dictionary will take effect.

Comment: Well, that explains it :) That's the one I was modifying :)

Answer (score 4):

"Ps" is also part of the `<Unrecognized>` section in my dictionary (and I never altered it). Apart from adding it to `<Recognized>` section, also remove it from the `<Unrecognized>` section.

```
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Unrecognized>
<!--      <Word>ps</Word> -->
       ...more entries
    </Unrecognized>
    <Recognized>
-      <Word>ps</Word>
       ...more entries
    </Recognized>
    <!-- more stuff -->
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that, good spot.  I have now removed it but unfortunately I am still getting the same warning?

Comment: @openshac: Strange, works for me. I'll edit the answer to reflect what my customdictionary.xml looks like.

Comment: I've got exactly the same in my CustomDictionary.xml as you. I even created a fresh test project but I am getting the same error. I have also tried putting "Ps" in the CasingExceptions section to no avail. However if I try creating variables like "Pi" and "Na" which are in the CasingException section then it works fine.  Can't see why these are different.

Comment: @openshac: I'm at a loss. I just added it to the recognized section, and commented out the entry in the unrecognized section, and it works. On the fly dis- and enabling the entry in the unrecognized section makes the warning dis- and reappear, without restarts or anything. Will see if I can find more...

Comment: Ok, what version of vS are you using? And which rule set are you using  I've got VS 10.0.30319 and am using the "Microsoft All Rules" rules set

Comment: @openshac: Identical: VS2010 (Premium) 10.0.30319.1, Microsoft All Rules.