# Visual Studio 2010 code analysis warning CA1704 for class named MultiString

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, warnings, code-analysis, ca1704

I'm having troubles with the code analysis tool in Visual Studio 2010; I have a class used to manipulate multi-strings, therfore I named my class `MultiString`. When I run the code analysis tool I get the warning:

> CA1704 : Microsoft.Naming : Correct the spelling of 'Multi' in type name 'MultiString'.

The same problem arises when is use the term `multiString` as paramter name or `IsMultiApplicationCard` as property name.

Thanks to the topic [Code Analysis - CA1704: Correct the spelling of 'Ps'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803290/code-analysis-ca1704-correct-the-spelling-of-ps) I found out that the term *multi* is unrecognized by default. Now I wonder why (I'm not a native speaker). Isn't *multi* a valid word? What word should I use instead? Or would you suggest to use *Multiapplication* and *Multistring*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MultiString` is parsed by Code Analysis into `multi, string`, which are then both checked against the dictionaries. `Multi` is a valid prefix for a word, but not a word by itself, i.e. `multicolored` is one word, so it should not be written `multi colored`. For this reason, the standard dictionary supplied by Microsoft in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\CustomDictionary.xml` explicitly specifies `multi` as unrecognised; that in turn means that [adding `Multi` to a custom dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx) is ineffective: Code Analysis will still reject it — but not explain why your dictionary entry is ineffective!

You best option seems to be to use `Multistring` (as you have noted yourself); second best would be to suppress CA1704 for this particular case; an administrator could presumably edit the standard dictionary, but that would need repeating after any updates, and seems a pretty dirty trick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but by _unrecognized_ I meant that is explicitly marked as unrecognized in the Microsoft dictionary. Therefore I can't add it to the recognized words (or at least it doesn't work as intended). Is _multistring_ a valid word? Or _multiapplication_? Normally I wouldn't care too much about those things but as I'm developing a C# library I thought it would be useful to honor the naming conventions.

Comment: @Korexio *"I meant that is explicitly marked as unrecognized in the Microsoft dictionary"* Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Multistring may not be a valid english word, but it's a valid "Microsoft english" word... :) It's even on a glossary [here on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc242598(v=prot.10).aspx). If this is exactly the multistring you're using in your code, then users of your library should be accustomed to the word.

Comment: @DaveShaw C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\CustomDictionary.xml contains multi under /Dictionary/Unrecognized/Word . No other reference available.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella Yes, that's exactly the multi-string I use. On [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the description for parameter `mszReaders` uses the term _multi-string_ .

Comment: @Korexio, cheers, looking down that list, there is a few exceptions with the multi% prefix (multiline, multipanel, etc). I see no reason why you cannot add your multistring to this list.

Comment: I'm by no means a linguist, so I'll just leave this link here and let you decide which form to use (TL;DR they should both be ok...)  http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/hyphen#hyphens_joining_prefixes

Comment: Adding it to the list of recognized words only works if I use it as a single word - _multistring_ and _multiapplication_. As _multi_ seems to be a prefix (and not a word as I thought) this should be the way to go. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since I had exactly the same problem with `multi` and @Korexio’s explanation has helped me to understand it, I have edited the answer to explain why one _cannot_ make MSVS accept `multi` – I hope the edit will be accepted!

Answer (score -1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264492.aspx?ppud=4 for details on how to fix this "violation". 'Multi' is not in the microsoft dictionary. You can change it to, say, 'Multiple'...or you can add 'Multi' to a custom dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but by _unrecognized_ I meant that is explicitly marked as unrecognized in the Microsoft dictionary. Therefore I can't add it to the recognized words (or at least it doesn't work as intended).

Comment: If you follow the link, it tells you how to create a custom dictionary to customize the code analysis checking behavior. Your custom dictionary is more than a simple list of words. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx for what can be put in it.

Comment: I'm familiar with code analysis dictionaries but in this special case it did not help to add terms/words; _Multi_ is marked as unrecognized in the basis/default Microsoft dictionary. This can not be overruled using a custom dictionary. For further information take a look at my comment to DaveShaw.